# Change font size of TeX code in LyX editor

Tags: lyx, fontsize

I'm working on a manuscript in LyX and using knitr to incorporate R code. The problem is that my inline TeX code is unwieldy to look at in LyX. How can I make the font appear smaller in the editor?

I think this has been answered previously on StackOverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028076/how-to-change-lyxs-default-font-for-latex-code/24037400#comment63186741_24037400) but I think it's out-of-date for LyX 2.1.4. I'm using a Mac if that makes a difference.

[image]

Comment: You can only change the font it seems, not the font size.

Comment: Well that's disappointing...

Comment: I'd suggest [getting involved](http://www.lyx.org/GetInvolved#toc7): "If you have a cool idea for a new feature, or comments in general about LyX, please share them with us. The more feedback we get from the users, the better we know what we should prioritize in the development effort."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the following in the document's *local layout*:

```
InsetLayout ERT
  Font
    Color               latex
    Family              typewriter
    Size                Small
  EndFont
End
```

(Tiny is an acceptable value as well.) This is an application of the general answer found there: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281207/87201